# installation cd/dvd for xp

Tags: windows-xp

i have a computer with windows xp home edition. I want to install Ubuntu. I am connect to the internet on a windows 10 computer. I want to create a cd/dvd for the xp computer. how is that done?

Comment: Because of the size of the Ubuntu .iso image, a DVD is now required. Do you have a CD drive/burner, or a DVD drive/burner, in your XP computer?

Answer (score -1):

Download Ubuntu, burn the image on a cd/DVD with a burner. 
Make sure the computer you want to installing Ubuntu on has the bios set to boot from the CD Rom.